# Is there a way to access standard animated drawables in Android?

Tags: android, animation, drawable

I stumbled upon a [list of all drawables for Android 2.2](http://androiddrawableexplorer.appspot.com/), which is very cool and includes references to the frames of the animation for downloading a file (stat_sys_download_anim0 and the rest).  There are six of these; I'd like to use them as an `AnimationDrawable`, which I could presumably do by specifying

```
<animation-list android:id="download" android:oneshot="false">
    <item android:drawable="@android:drawable/stat_sys_download_anim0" android:duration="150" />
    <item android:drawable="@android:drawable/stat_sys_download_anim1" android:duration="50" />
    <item android:drawable="@android:drawable/stat_sys_download_anim2" android:duration="50" />
    <item android:drawable="@android:drawable/stat_sys_download_anim3" android:duration="50" />
    <item android:drawable="@android:drawable/stat_sys_download_anim4" android:duration="50" />
    <item android:drawable="@android:drawable/stat_sys_download_anim5" android:duration="50" />
</animation-list>
```

However, presumably such a drawable already exists in the standard Android resources ... I just can't find it.  Is it available to Ordinary Folk?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You will find the drawable XML in your Android SDK installation as `stat_sys_download.xml`. It is in the SDK as [`android.R.drawable.stat_sys_download`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.drawable.html#stat_sys_download).

That being said, you really should consider copying these from your Android SDK into your project. Device manufacturers can and do change these images. If you want to maintain consistency across devices, you will want to have your own local copy.

Comment: That's what I was looking for, thanks—and actually I'd prefer to mimic the device's look and feel in things like notifications, so in some senses this is preferable!